# What do the various ISubject implementations do and when would they be used?

Tags: system.reactive

I have a fairly good idea of what the Subject class does and when to use it, but I've just been looking through the language reference on msdn and see there are various other ISubject implementations such as:

- AsyncSubject
- BehaviorSubject
- ReplaySubject

As the documentation is pretty thin on the ground, whats the point of each of these types and under what situations would you use them?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These subjects all share a common property - they take some (or all) of what gets posted to them via OnNext and record it and play it back to you - i.e. they take a Hot Observable and make it Cold. This means, that if you Subscribe to any of these more than once (i.e. Subscribe => Unsubscribe => Subscribe again), you'll see *at least one* of the same value again.

**ReplaySubject**: Every time you subscribe to the Subject, you get the entire history of what has been posted replayed back to you, as fast as possible (or a subset, like the last *n* items)

**AsyncSubject**: Always plays back the last item posted and completes, but only after the source has completed. This Subject is awesome for async functions, since you can write them without worrying about race conditions: even if someone Subscribes *after* the async method completes, they get the result.

**BehaviorSubject**: Kind of like ReplaySubject but with a buffer of one, so you always get the last thing that was posted. You also can provide an initial value. Always provides one item instantly on Subscribe.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was wondering the same. Another thing I don't quite understand is how Subject and its variants are different from or complement the Publish/Multicast functionality? Isn't subscribing multiple observers to a Subject the same as what Multicast achieves?

Comment: @Matthias Yes, it's exactly what Multicast achieves, except for it gives you a way to disconnect them all in one go via `IConnectableObservable`

Answer (score 7):

In light of the latest version ([v1.0.2856.0](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/1b554ca0-7e23-4603-8b00-7753acf08c83)) and to keep this question up to date, there has been a new set of subject classes:

`FastSubject`, `FastBehaviorSubject`, `FastAsyncSubject` and `FastReplaySubject`

As per the [release notes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/1b554ca0-7e23-4603-8b00-7753acf08c83) they

> are much faster than regular subjects
>   but:
>
> - don’t decouple producer and consumer    by an IScheduler
>     (effectively    limiting them to
>     ImmediateScheduler);
> - don’t protect against stack overflow;
> - don’t synchronize input messages.
>
> Fast subjects are used by Publish and
>   Prune operators if no scheduler is
>   specified.

Comment: These classes have since been removed. Now subjects are "fast" by default and can have the protections added by calling [`Synchronize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229016(v=VS.103).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

In regards to AsyncSubject

This code:

```
        var s = new AsyncSubject<int>();
        s.OnNext(1);
        s.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        s.OnNext(2);
        s.OnNext(3);
        s.OnCompleted();
```

prints a single value 3. And it prints same if subscription is moved to after completion. So it plays back not the first, but the last item, plays it after completion (until complete, it does not produce values), and it does not work like Subject before completion.
See [this Prune discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976593/use-case-for-prune) for more info (AsyncSubject is basically the same as Prune)

Answer (score 4):

Paul's answer pretty much nails it. There's a few things worth adding, though:

<strike>**AsyncSubject** works as Paul says, but only after the *source* completes. Before that, it works like `Subject` (where "live" values are received by subscribers)</strike>

**AsyncSubject** has changed since I last ran tests against it. It no longer acts as a live subject before completion, but waits for completion before it emits a value. And, as Sergey mentions, it returns the last value, not the first (though I should have caught that as that's always been the case)

**AsyncSubject** is used by `Prune`, `FromAsyncPattern`, `ToAsync` and probably a few others

**BehaviorSubject** is used by overloads of `Publish` that accept an initial value

**ReplaySubject** is used by `Replay`

*NOTE: All operator references above refer to the publishing set of operators as they were before they were replaced with generalised publish operators in rev 2838 (Christmas '10) as it has been mentioned that the original operators will be re-added*

Comment: Ah, didn't know that about AsyncSubject - awesome!