# Rx IObservable: How to make a concrete push collection?

Tags: .net, system.reactive

There are zillions of concrete implementations of IEnumerable: `List<T>`, `Dictionary<T>`, etc. What concrete implementations of IObservable are available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What concrete implementations of IObservable are available?

`AnonymousObservable<T>` (internal), `ConnectableObservable<T>`, `ListObservable<T>`...

But the most common way to create IObservables is through System.Reactive's functions and extension methods (e.g. `ToObservable()`) ([example](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples#toc11))

Comment: It's worth pointing out that almost all the extension methods use `AnonymousObservable` and closures.

Answer (score 4):

Rx's ISubject implementations are some of the most common implementations of the IObservable interface. The list of the subject classes include:

```
Subject<T>
AsyncSubject<T>
BehaviorSubject<T>
ReplaySubject<T>
```

and the new

```
FastSubject<T>
FastAsyncSubject<T>
FastBehaviorSubject<T>
FastReplaySubject<T>
```

Subject classes represent objects that implement `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` and are used throughout the inner workings of the Rx library.  They are also pretty invaluable if you are creating your own extention methods.  You can find an explanation of each of these implementations on my [recent question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787276/what-do-the-various-isubject-implementations-do-and-when-would-they-be-used) (no pun intended).

*As Mauricio Scheffer mentioned, it is more commmon to use the `Observable` classes static methods and `IObservable` extention methods (System.Linq namespace) to retrieve IObservable instances.*